# How to change the sticky-top position on large devices to fixed-top on small devices in the Bootstrap 4 navbar?

Tags: bootstrap-4

could you tell me if there is any way to change the position of my navbar from sticky-top on large devices to fixed-top on small devices.[image: Large devices]

```
<nav id="menu" class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
```

[image: small devices]

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with javascript.
First, remove the sticky top class from your navbar element

so, it should look like this:

```
<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
```

And then add this script in your head tag so that this script get loaded with Domcontent.

```
var width = window.screen.width;
var nav = document.getElementById('menu');
if(width < 768){
    if(nav.hasClass('sticky-top')){
        nav.classList.remove("sticky-top");
    }
    nav.classList.add("fixed-top");
}
else{
    if(nav.hasClass('fixed-top')){
        nav.classList.remove("fixed-top");
    }
    nav.classList.add('sticky-top');
}
```

I hope it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS media queries to target in small devices.

Add this in your style sheet, it should do the job. Make sure your style sheet is added below your bootstrap.css file.

```
// Small devices
@media (max-width: 767px) { 

  #menu sticky-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
  }
}
```